# How to get count of Dictionary Value Collection in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, data-structures

I'm trying to get the count of a dictionary's value collection, where a field of the collection item, matches the key in the collection, as well as the type.

So my collection looks like this, note the object is initialized, this is just pseudo code:

```
var results = Dictionary<string, List<CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult>();
```

Now the **CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult** is a data transfer object, that maps to the rows returned from my query.

```
public class CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string College { get; set; }
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; } 
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCoursesSQLResult> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

You will notice that my **CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult** class also has a collection of **StudentCoursesSQLResult** objects. This is the list I'm trying to get a count of, based on two conditions.

First that the course, which is the string KEY in the dictionary, matches the course of the **StudentCoursesSQLResult** and then I need to filter on the **StudentCoursesSQLResult**.Type.

Here is the **StudentCoursesSQLResult** class:

```
public class StudentCoursesSQLResult
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now to get the count I'm looping over my dictionary and outputting headers for each key, this is where I'm trying to output the count for the dictionary's value collection.

```
    foreach(var result in results) {
       <span class="label label-default label-fat">
          @result.Value.SelectMany(r => r.Courses).Count(c => c.Course == result.Key && c.Type == "required")
       </span>
    }
```

But for some reason it's returning zero, when I know it shouldn't be.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Everything I've found so far online has said to use SelectMany, but I'm not having any luck.

Here is a screenshot of the debug output for a single course for the dictionary's value collection, where the Type is "required".

[image]

Comment: Stupid question , but have you checked that your string comparisons are actually returning true?

Comment: Strange...The strings do match up, so I'm not sure why I'm not getting any results. See my edit above.

Comment: Yes. Those are the courses, which I'm grouping my results by. I use the keys as headings, and then each key has a value, which is a collection of CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult objects, which each contain a collection of StudentCoursesSQLResult.

Comment: I just updated the screenshot so you can get a better view of the dictionary and it's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screen shot, *"Advanced French I: Structure and Expression"* doesn't match the key of *"Medieval Art and Architecture"*, which explains the incorrect count.

Instead, filter the `CourseEnrollmentsByStudentSQLResult` collection to those matching the dictionary key, then select all courses in those matched records, and finally count the courses that are "required".

```
@result.Value.Where(r => r.Course == result.Key)
             .SelectMany(r => r.Courses)
             .Count(c => c.Type == "required");
```

Comment: Thanks Grant. Looks like I was trying to do the Key check last, instead of first. The screenshot does have the correct key, I just expanded one of the nodes, so people could see the Type strings did match up. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

A variation on vivat if you want to do this in a program:

```
  var cnt = selections.Where(r => r.Key == "Items").SelectMany(r => r.Value).Count();
```

"Items" is the Key value within the collection.  In my case I created this collection:

```
  Dictionary<string, string[]> selections = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Then added a simple set of values based on a key:

```
  selections.Add("Items", txtItems.Text.Replace("\n", "").Split('\r'));
```

Later on I wanted to check if there had been any values set so I used the above method to count.  It works great and in initial testing it helped me discover I needed to cleanup text entries before setting them up.